# why does jQuery selectric plugin not work

Tags: jquery, plugins

I follow the guide provided by jQuery selectric website 
https://selectric.js.org/

but when I do the second part, include the  jQuery Selectric in the head tab

it turned out the Webstorm can't resolve the plugin, so it brought the outcome that I could not use the selectric method afterward, what should I do ?

for the CSS, I went to the demo page and chose Flat(dark blue), and download the css, drag that css file to my directory, and drag it into the head tab, file name called selectric (2).css

the head part :

```
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    <!--    <script src="jquery-main.js"></script>-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.selectric.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="selectric (2).css">

    </head>
```

the jQuery part :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#mymenu").selectiric()
})
</script>
```

the html part :

```
   <h1>rendering theme</h1>
<form>
    <select name="" id="mymenu">
        <option value="">a</option>
        <option value="">b</option>
        <option value="">c</option>
        <option value="">d</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: your select is invalid - also please post code in a [mcve] and not pictures of code otherwise your question is off topic for SO - see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: the console said: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found),so it means the path is incorrect ?

Comment: @JoshCaffery it does, yes. Check exactly which file it's trying to load, though. Also note @Pete's point that your HTML for the `select` is invalid. You need to fix that too

Comment: ok, i fixed the html part, i added select tab with ID named mymenu for letting jQuery select it, but still not working

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo.

selectric instead of selectiric

In the original message there is:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#mymenu").selectiric()
})
</script>
```

But it should be

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#mymenu").selectric()
})
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did you mean *selectiric* instead of *selectric*? it's exactly the opposite...